# What precisely does Perforator measure to determine a WPF application's frame rate?

Tags: wpf

The WPF profiling tool Perforator can display the frame rate of a running WPF program. Does any know precisely what it is measuring about the program to calculate this figure, and if it possible for a program to measure its own frame rate in the same way?

Comment: Using ETW Event Tracing in WPF seems to be the official way  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/09/26/etw-event-tracing-in-wpf.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got you properly you are looking for `CompositionTarget.Rendering` event.

Take a look on the sample: [How to: Render on a Per Frame Interval Using CompositionTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748838.aspx)